# How to flatten the result of lapply in R?

Tags: r, plot

Consider the code below:

```
fun <- function(theta1,theta2,x){

theta1*x/(x+theta2)

}

x <- seq(from = -5,to = 5, by = 1)
y <- lapply(c(0.04,0.06,0.08,0.1),fun,x=x,theta1 = 200)
```

When I select the first element `y[1]` the result is:

```
[[1]]
[1] #some number
```

I want to get ride of `[[1]]` when I use `y[1]` so that I can plot y:

```
plot(x,y[1],col=1)
```

**Edit**

Someone also mentioned `unlist` which works!

Comment: `plot(x,y[[1]],col=1)`

Comment: Thanks! what is the name of `[[]]`?

Comment: Use `sapply` instead of `lapply`.